# How was it possible to install iOS app directly from a browser?

Tags: ios, ad-hoc-distribution, in-house-distribution

I was wondering how was this website able to offer an iOS app for download directly from the browser bypassing the App Store?

(*Please be advised that this is an adult-oriented app.*)
http://app.941hd.com/ios_download.html

Answer (score 2):

It seems they're using an enterprise certificate, which is intended for in-house corporate developers.

iOS Apps signed with those certificates can be downloaded and installed through a link by anyone, regardless of whether or not the developer has your UDID.

They would be violating their developer agreement with Apple and can expect to have their account suspended when Apple finds out.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on exactly this implementation but a similar thing could be done using B2B distribution method. More info [here.](https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/)

Answer (score 1):

You can distribute your app from a web page simply by creating a download link for the `.ipa`.
When opened in iOS, the application will be downloaded and installed on the device, if the device is registered on the `provisioning profile` used to sign the `.ipa` or if the provisioning profile is `inHouse`.

Answer (score 1):

They have enrolled a Enterprise Account of Apple and they have made Enterprise App , which can be distributed via website and can be directly downloaded from browser .

Answer (score 0):

There are online tools that simplify this process of sharing, for example https://abbashare.com or https://diawi.com

Create an ipa file from xcode with adhoc or inhouse profile, and upload this file on these site.

I prefer abbashare because save file on your dropbox and you can delete it whenever you want